# Connect to Google DataStore through Spring data and outside Gae

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'm looking for a way to create a custom JPA repository for Google Data Store from a standalone application (Spring Boot) not hosted on Gae. I want to use Spring Data to acheive that. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Datastore can be accessed via client libraries outside of App Engine. They run on the "v1 API" which went GA in August, 2016. There is a [Client Library Java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-datastore) which is probably a good starting point for building something for Spring Data.

As a note, you can use the GQL language that the Cloud Datastore service supports. It is SQL-Like in structure.

Take a read of our [GQL reference docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/gql_reference).